# Color at the top and bottom of chart

Tags: pine-script

Evening all,

I currently use the below script to monitor markets opening. But with other indicators on top of it can get cluttered.

https://uk.tradingview.com/script/Jv0RtKiB-Pre-and-Market-Openings/

I am wondering it there is a way to just have a strip of color at the top and bottom of the chart. That way I can easily visualize without the screen being cluttered.

I have tried plotshape square which works but its not what I am after.

Is there a way for it to be a constant color (no breaks like plotshape square)?

Thank you for your time.

This is what I first tried with the plot squares (but I didn't like the spacing):
[image]

```
//@version=4
study(title="Sessions", shorttitle="Sessions", overlay=true)
///London End of Session Start
LonInput = input('0600-1200:1234567', title="London", group = "IGOR Sessions - Bottom Color Stripe") 
LonSession = time("1", LonInput)
plotshape(LonSession, title="Lon", style=shape.square, location=location.bottom, color=color.yellow, transp=0, size=size.tiny)
///London End of Session Finish

///New York End of Session Start
NYInput = input('1200-2000:1234567', title="New York", group = "IGOR Sessions - Bottom Color Stripe") 
NYSession = time("1", NYInput)
plotshape(NYSession, title="Asia", style=shape.square, location=location.bottom, color=color.blue, transp=0, size=size.tiny)
///New York End of Session Finish

///Asia End of Session Start
AsiaInput = input('0000-0600:1234567', title="Asia", group = "IGOR Sessions - Bottom Color Stripe") 
AsiaSession = time("1", AsiaInput)
plotshape(AsiaSession, title="Asia", style=shape.square, location=location.bottom, color=color.purple, transp=0, size=size.tiny)
///Asia End of Session Finish


///Close
CloseInput = input('2000-0000:1234567', title="Close", group = "Sessions - Bottom Color Stripe") 
CloseSession = time("1", CloseInput)
plotshape(CloseSession, title="Close", style=shape.square, location=location.bottom, color=color.red, transp=0, size=size.tiny)
```

####################Update 22/03/2021 ###############

I have now playing with a different method by creating a low and lower and then filling the space. But this is based off the days low. Is there a way to use the location=location.bottom, as I would like to have it in the same location as where the plot shape was.

[image]

```
//@version=4
study(title="Sessions", shorttitle="Sessions", overlay=true)

london = input(title="London", type=input.session, defval="0600-1200:1234567")
newyork = input(title="NY", type=input.session, defval="1200-2000:1234567")
asia = input(title="Asia", type=input.session, defval="0000-0600:1234567")
closed = input(title="Close", type=input.session, defval="2000-0000:1234567")

colourcheck = 1.0
boxheight = input(title="Box Height", type=input.float, defval=3)

DailyHigh = security(syminfo.tickerid, 'D', high)
DailyLow = security(syminfo.tickerid, 'D', low)

dayrange = DailyHigh - DailyLow

BottomoLowBox = DailyLow - (dayrange * 0.01 * boxheight)

BarInSession(sess) => time(timeframe.period, sess) != 0

//LONDON
LonTop = plot(DailyLow and BarInSession(london) ? DailyLow : na, title="London High", style=plot.style_linebr, linewidth=3, color=na)
LonBottom = plot(DailyLow and BarInSession(london) ? BottomoLowBox : na, title="London Low", style=plot.style_linebr, linewidth=3, color=na)
fill(LonTop,LonBottom,color=color.green, title="London Low Box", transp=50) // box 2 top fill

//NEW YORK
NYTop = plot(DailyLow and BarInSession(newyork) ? DailyLow : na, title="New York High", style=plot.style_linebr, linewidth=3, color=na)
NYBottom = plot(DailyLow and BarInSession(newyork) ? BottomoLowBox : na, title="New York Low", style=plot.style_linebr, linewidth=3, color=na)
fill(NYTop,NYBottom,color=color.purple, title="New York Low Box", transp=50)

//ASIA
AsiaTop = plot(DailyLow and BarInSession(asia) ? DailyLow : na, title="Asia High", style=plot.style_linebr, linewidth=3, color=na)
AsiaBottom = plot(DailyLow and BarInSession(asia) ? BottomoLowBox : na, title="Asia Low", style=plot.style_linebr, linewidth=3, color=na)
fill(AsiaTop,AsiaBottom,color=color.yellow, title="Asia Low Box", transp=50)

//CLOSE
CloseTop = plot(DailyLow and BarInSession(closed) ? DailyLow : na, title="Close High", style=plot.style_linebr, linewidth=3, color=na)
CloseBottom = plot(DailyLow and BarInSession(closed) ? BottomoLowBox : na, title="Close Low", style=plot.style_linebr, linewidth=3, color=na)
fill(CloseTop,CloseBottom,color=color.red, title="Close Low Box", transp=50)
```

If some could assist, is it possible to somehow use the "location" from plotshape or is there a better way to do this?

#####Update 22/03/2021 @ 2140 ##########

This is where I am currently with scripting this. Is there a better way and or can any improvements be made to the script.
[image]

```
//@version=4
study("Test Delete", overlay=true)

//Pre and Market Opens
MorningAsiaTop = input(title="Morning Market Asia Top", type=input.session, defval="0000-0230:1234567", group = "Pre and Market Timings")
AfternoonAsiaTop = input(title="Afternoon Market Asia Top", type=input.session, defval="0330-0505:1234567", group = "Pre and Market Timings")

PreMarketLondonTop = input(title="Pre Market London Top", type=input.session, defval="0505-0750:1234567", group = "Pre and Market Timings")
MarketLondonTop = input(title="Market London Top", type=input.session, defval="0800-1130:1234567", group = "Pre and Market Timings")

PreMarketNYTop = input(title="Pre Market New York Top", type=input.session, defval="1130-1430:1234567", group = "Pre and Market Timings")
MarketNYTop = input(title="Market New York Top", type=input.session, defval="1430-2100:1234567", group = "Pre and Market Timings")


//
AsiaBottom = input(title=" Asia Bottom", type=input.session, defval="0000-0600:1234567", group = " Timings")
LondonBottom = input(title=" London Bottom", type=input.session, defval="0600-1200:1234567", group = " Timings")
NYBottom = input(title=" New York Bottom", type=input.session, defval="1200-2000:1234567", group = " Timings")
CloseBottom = input(title=" Asia Bottom", type=input.session, defval="2000-0000:1234567", group = " Timings")

colourcheck = 1.0
boxheight = input(title="Box Height", type=input.float, defval=3)

DailyHigh = security(syminfo.tickerid, 'D', high+1500)
DailyLow = security(syminfo.tickerid, 'D', low-1500)

dayrange = DailyHigh - DailyLow

BottomLowBox = DailyLow + (dayrange * 0.01 * boxheight)
TopLowBox = DailyHigh - (dayrange * 0.01 * boxheight)

BarInSession(sess) => time(timeframe.period, sess) != 0

//ASIA
AsiaBottomH = plot(DailyLow and BarInSession(AsiaBottom) ? DailyLow : na, title="Asia Bottom High", style=plot.style_linebr, linewidth=3, color=na)
AsiaBottomL = plot(DailyLow and BarInSession(AsiaBottom) ? BottomLowBox : na, title="Asia Bottom Low", style=plot.style_linebr, linewidth=3, color=na)
fill(AsiaBottomH,AsiaBottomL,color=color.purple, title="Asia Low Box", transp=0)


AsiaTopH = plot(DailyHigh and BarInSession(MorningAsiaTop) ? DailyHigh : na, title="Morning Asia Top High", style=plot.style_linebr, linewidth=3, color=na)
AsiaTopL = plot(DailyHigh and BarInSession(MorningAsiaTop) ? TopLowBox : na, title="Morning Asia Top Low", style=plot.style_linebr, linewidth=3, color=na)
fill(AsiaTopH,AsiaTopL,color=#301934, title="Asia Top Box", transp=0)

AsiaPreTopH = plot(DailyHigh and BarInSession(AfternoonAsiaTop) ? DailyHigh : na, title="Afternoon Asia Top High", style=plot.style_linebr, linewidth=3, color=na)
AsiaPreTopL = plot(DailyHigh and BarInSession(AfternoonAsiaTop) ? TopLowBox : na, title="Afternoon Asia Top Low", style=plot.style_linebr, linewidth=3, color=na)
fill(AsiaPreTopH,AsiaPreTopL,color=#301934, title="Asia Top Box", transp=0)


//LONDON
LonBottomH = plot(DailyLow and BarInSession(LondonBottom) ? DailyLow : na, title="London Bottom High", style=plot.style_linebr, linewidth=3, color=na)
LonBottomL = plot(DailyLow and BarInSession(LondonBottom) ? BottomLowBox : na, title="London Bottom Low", style=plot.style_linebr, linewidth=3, color=na)
fill(LonBottomH,LonBottomL,color=color.green, title="London Low Box", transp=0)

LonTopH = plot(DailyHigh and BarInSession(MarketLondonTop) ? DailyHigh : na, title="London Top High", style=plot.style_linebr, linewidth=3, color=na)
LonTopL = plot(DailyHigh and BarInSession(MarketLondonTop) ? TopLowBox : na, title="London Top Low", style=plot.style_linebr, linewidth=3, color=na)
fill(LonTopH,LonTopL,color=#013220, title="London Top Box", transp=0)

LonPreTopH = plot(DailyHigh and BarInSession(PreMarketLondonTop) ? DailyHigh : na, title="London Top High", style=plot.style_linebr, linewidth=3, color=na)
LonPreTopL = plot(DailyHigh and BarInSession(PreMarketLondonTop) ? TopLowBox : na, title="London Top Low", style=plot.style_linebr, linewidth=3, color=na)
fill(LonPreTopH,LonPreTopL,color=#013220, title="Pre London Top Box", transp=50)

//NEW YORK
NYBottomH = plot(DailyLow and BarInSession(NYBottom) ? DailyLow : na, title="New York Bottom High", style=plot.style_linebr, linewidth=3, color=na)
NYBottomL = plot(DailyLow and BarInSession(NYBottom) ? BottomLowBox : na, title="New York Bottom Low", style=plot.style_linebr, linewidth=3, color=na)
fill(NYBottomH,NYBottomL,color=color.blue, title="New York Low Box", transp=0)

NYTopH = plot(DailyHigh and BarInSession(MarketNYTop) ? DailyHigh : na, title="New York Top High", style=plot.style_linebr, linewidth=3, color=na)
NYTopL = plot(DailyHigh and BarInSession(MarketNYTop) ? TopLowBox : na, title="New York Top Low", style=plot.style_linebr, linewidth=3, color=na)
fill(NYTopH,NYTopL,color=#00008b, title="New York Top Box", transp=0)

NYPreTopH = plot(DailyHigh and BarInSession(PreMarketNYTop) ? DailyHigh : na, title="New York Top High", style=plot.style_linebr, linewidth=3, color=na)
NYPreTopL = plot(DailyHigh and BarInSession(PreMarketNYTop) ? TopLowBox : na, title="New York Top Low", style=plot.style_linebr, linewidth=3, color=na)
fill(NYPreTopH,NYPreTopL,color=#00008b, title="Pre New York Top Box", transp=50)

//CLOSE
CloseBottomH = plot(DailyLow and BarInSession(CloseBottom) ? DailyLow : na, title="Close Bottom High", style=plot.style_linebr, linewidth=3, color=na)
CloseBottomL = plot(DailyLow and BarInSession(CloseBottom) ? BottomLowBox : na, title="Close Bottom Low", style=plot.style_linebr, linewidth=3, color=na)
fill(CloseBottomH,CloseBottomL,color=color.red, title="Close Low Box", transp=0)
```

######Update 24/03/2021 @ 1500

I have resorted back to using the plotshape functions.

But this question has offered various ways to achieve what I was aiming though not completely what I desired.

Marked as answered.

Comment: Maybe it's better to use the function `bgcolor`.

Comment: Evening AnyDozer I hope you are well. I originally used bgcolor but it covered the whole chart. Are you saying there is a way to use bgcolor and for it to appear just at the top or bottom of the chart?

Comment: Thank you, I'm fine. I assumed that the background fill would suit you, but the fill is only possible over the entire height of the chart.

Comment: Yeah I don't want to fill the whole chart. I have played with bgcolor to see if there was a way to only partial fill but didnt have any luck. 
I am currently reading to see if there is a way to read the y axis scale so that the box method above would scale when I move the y axis.
Do you know if that is possible (y axis scaling)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know it's not exactly what you wanted, but it might suit you just fine.

```
//@version=4
study(title="Help (Sessions)", shorttitle="Sessions", overlay=false)

london = input(title="London", type=input.session, defval="0600-1200:1234567")
newyork = input(title="NY", type=input.session, defval="1200-2000:1234567")
asia = input(title="Asia", type=input.session, defval="0000-0600:1234567")
closed = input(title="Close", type=input.session, defval="2000-0000:1234567")

colourcheck = 1.0
boxheight = input(title="Box Height", type=input.float, defval=3)

DailyHigh = security(syminfo.tickerid, 'D', high)
DailyLow = security(syminfo.tickerid, 'D', low)

dayrange = DailyHigh - DailyLow

BottomoLowBox = DailyLow - (dayrange * 0.01 * boxheight)

BarInSession(sess) => time(timeframe.period, sess) != 0

//LONDON
LonTop = plot(DailyLow and BarInSession(london) ? 1 : na, title="London High", style=plot.style_histogram, linewidth=6, color=color.green, transp=50)
// LonBottom = plot(DailyLow and BarInSession(london) ? BottomoLowBox : na, title="London Low", style=plot.style_linebr, linewidth=3, color=na)
// fill(LonTop,LonBottom,color=color.green, title="London Low Box", transp=50) // box 2 top fill

// //NEW YORK
NYTop = plot(DailyLow and BarInSession(newyork) ? 1 : na, title="New York High", style=plot.style_histogram, linewidth=6, color=color.purple, transp=50)
// NYBottom = plot(DailyLow and BarInSession(newyork) ? BottomoLowBox : na, title="New York Low", style=plot.style_linebr, linewidth=3, color=na)
// fill(NYTop,NYBottom,color=color.purple, title="New York Low Box", transp=50)

// //ASIA
AsiaTop = plot(DailyLow and BarInSession(asia) ? 1 : na, title="Asia High", style=plot.style_histogram, linewidth=6, color=color.yellow, transp=50)
// AsiaBottom = plot(DailyLow and BarInSession(asia) ? BottomoLowBox : na, title="Asia Low", style=plot.style_linebr, linewidth=3, color=na)
// fill(AsiaTop,AsiaBottom,color=color.yellow, title="Asia Low Box", transp=50)

// //CLOSE
CloseTop = plot(DailyLow and BarInSession(closed) ? 1 : na, title="Close High", style=plot.style_histogram, linewidth=6, color=color.red, transp=50)
// CloseBottom = plot(DailyLow and BarInSession(closed) ? BottomoLowBox : na, title="Close Low", style=plot.style_linebr, linewidth=3, color=na)
// fill(CloseTop,CloseBottom,color=color.red, title="Close Low Box", transp=50)
```

[image]